# Save outputs to new directory in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to identify all .kml in a specific directory and save them into a new directory. Is this possible? I'm able to print the file path but I would like to use Python to copy those files to a new directory.

Here is my code so far:

```
import os

# traverse whole directory
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\file_path_here'):
    # select file name
    for file in files:
        # check the extension of files
        if file.endswith('.kml'):
            # print whole path of files
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: Have you googled "how to copy a file with Python?"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP needs to show some effort.

Comment: have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile

Comment: Thanks for the resources! I issue was I was using shutil.copyfile rather than shutil.copy

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os

# traverse whole directory
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\file_path_here'):
    # select file name
    for each_file in files:
        # check the extension of files
        if each_file.endswith('.kml'):
            # print whole path of files
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
            kml_file = open(each_file, "r")
            content = kml_file.read()
            file.close()
            with open('newfile.kml', 'w') as f:
                 f.write(content)
```